# Why does this outputting numbers in the file not the machine name?

Tags: powershell

The file that I'm outputting doesnt contain the $machine and if its valid or not, it contains numbers. How do I get this to output the machine name and if its valid or not?

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$enddate = Get-Date 
$machines=(Get-ADComputer -filter * -SearchBase 'OU=this,OU=is,OU=my,DC=domain,DC=com' -Properties * | Select Name, lastlogondate |Where-Object {$_.LastLogonDate -lt ($enddate).AddMonths(-2)} |Sort  lastlogondate).name
foreach ($machine in $machines) 
{
  if (test-Connection -ComputerName $machine -count 1 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) 
         {
            Write-Output "$machine is valid" 
         }
            Write-Output "$machine is not valid" | Export-Csv 
  c:\machine_not_valid.csv -Append -NoClobber -NoTypeInformation
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Export-Csv` expects an object, not a string. It then uses the properties of this object as headers for the CSV.

It is outputting numbers because it is receiving `string` as input, which has the single property `Length`

You also have an error in your code where the `"$machine is not valid"` part is outside of the `if` statement and not in an `else` statement.

If you have multiple values, `Export-Csv` is the way to go. If you only have one, use `Out-File`as you will not need to create an object:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$enddate = Get-Date 
$machines=(Get-ADComputer -filter * -SearchBase 'OU=this,OU=is,OU=my,DC=domain,DC=com' -Properties * | Select Name, lastlogondate |Where-Object {$_.LastLogonDate -lt ($enddate).AddMonths(-2)} |Sort  lastlogondate).name

foreach ($machine in $machines) 
{
  if (test-Connection -ComputerName $machine -count 1 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) 
         {
            Write-Output "$machine is valid" 
         }else{
            Write-Output "$machine is not valid" | Export-Csv c:\machine_not_valid.csv -Append -NoClobber
         }  
}
```